# TibrvException Not connected to daemon

Tags: java, tibco

I have an application in java that use Tibco and from a sudden I just was disconnected to daemon and each time I try to send a message I got a

```
TibrvException[error=21,message=Not connected to daemon]
```

It does not auto-reconnect.
In the daemon webpage administration I don't see any restart or advisory.

Do you know what could have make my application disconnected from daemon?
How can I recover from this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Use tibrvlisten and invoked with the correct TIBCO RV SND parameters. This should verify that the rvd is active on the network.

Tibrvlisten should be in the RV installation 'bin' dir. It's invoked like this:

Tibrvlisten -service 'service port' -network 'network multicast ip' -daemoin 'daemon name and port' "listen subject"

There is also a java version in the rv examples directory that you can compile and use

Comment: Yes, it was working since several months. And restarting application solved the problem. It is why I think the installation is ok. Thanks for the answer.